# Where style.css should be in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am developing my own theme for wordpress, I'm also using SASS to write the CSS, and I want the final compiled CSS to be minified... my question is:

What would happen if I set SASS to compile the CSS in my `style.css` file (the one that is in the main folder of "themes"), would Wordpress be able to read it without problems?

Or should I leave `style.css` blank and compile the CSS in a file inside a CSS fodler, for example: `css/main.css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or should I leave style.css blank and compile the CSS in a file inside
>   a CSS fodler, for example: css/main.css?

This is the best way to do it, and the way 99% of custom theme developers use. Just call main.css with `@import` and that's it

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the style.css file alone and create another file like you stated. I'd also make sure to not include the default style.css and only the one you generated.  If you look at great starter themes, that is what they do.  For example, https://github.com/roots/roots.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how large your css file will be. For larger projects, I would split up my stylesheets into global.css, layout.css, mobile.css, tablet.css, put them in a subdirectory and @import them into the main style.css in the theme's root folder.

If it is a simple site that doesn't require structuring your css in such a way, you can have style.css and style.sass located in the same root folder of your theme.